# my fonts look completly different on other machines

Tags: flash-cs4

i just published a flash site for a friend to check out and they're saying that the 
font is completely different than what it's supposed to be... should be sans serif and it's a serif font.

the text in question are buttons and movie clips.

i was under the impression that with flash, fonts should look exactly the same everywhere.

what am i doing wrong? how can i get the font i'm see/using to appear on all other machines
that view my site?

thanks,

_boz

Answer (score 2):

Fonts are not embedded by default

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts/